# Divide values divided by tab, in their own variable

Tags: python, file, split

I create an output file in a different process, which has 2 values with a tab separating each other. Each line has 2 values and newline, so you always have 2 values per line.

I would like to get the first and second value in 2 different variables, and use them; but I am having hard time to split them.

I do not know the lenght of each string, I just know that there is a tab in between, so I can't count the characters and slice. How do you accomplish this in Python?

Comment: `x, y = line.split()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your lines are stored in a list called `my_lines` you can do:

```
for line in my_lines:
  val1, val2 = line.strip().split("\t", 1)
```

Comment: you don't have to have all the lines in `my_lines`, you can iterate the file with the file_handle like: `for line in f:`

Comment: Sure, I was just giving a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> s = """This     is  demo    string"""
>>> s.split("\t")
['This ', 'is ', 'demo ', 'string']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
    value1, value2 = line.strip().split("\t", maxsplit=1)
    #print(value1, value2)
```

`maxsplit=1` keyword argument ensures that you split only once since you said you only have two values which are tab separated.